# Django Deleting a GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, generic-foreign-key, generic-relations

I am trying to implement an activity feed following [this tutorial](http://ryanberg.net/blog/2008/jun/24/basics-creating-tumblelog-django/).

I would like to delete an acitivity(ie a comment has been added)when the corresponding object, ie the comment itself, has been removed. This doesn't seem to cascade.

Is there any way to achieve this without adding a GenericRelation? It is possible to delete the corresponding activity by using postdelete signal. Is that the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but maybe it's better using a [pre_delete signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-delete) because you will be able to access to the instance pk.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

from yourapp.models import Comment, Activity

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Comment)
def pre_delete_receiver(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    # code that delete the related objects
    # As you don't have generic relation you should manually
    # find related actitities
    ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
    Activity.objects.filter(content_type=ctype, object_id=instance.pk).delete()
```